# Value as arguments for variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to make a sum function using variadic template.

```
#include <iostream>

int sum() {
   return 0;
}

template <int first, int ...Rest>
int sum() {
   return first + sum<Rest...>();
}

int main() {
   sum<1, 2, 3>();
}
```

But I got an error like this:

```
test.cc: In instantiation of 'int sum() [with int first = 3; int ...Rest = {}]':  
test.cc:10:31:   recursively required from 'int sum() [with int first = 2; int ...Rest = {3}]'
test.cc:10:31:   required from 'int sum() [with int first = 1; int ...Rest = {2, 3}]'
test.cc:14:17:   required from here
test.cc:10:31: error: no matching function for call to 'sum<>()'
    return first + sum<Rest...>();
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.cc:9:5: note: candidate: 'template<int first, int ...Rest> int sum()'        
 int sum() {
     ^~~
test.cc:9:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:10:31: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'first'
    return first + sum<Rest...>();
```

so I changed

```
int sum { return 0; }
```

to

```
template<int first>
int sum { return first; }
```

but I got an another error:

```
test.cc:11:31: error: call of overloaded 'sum<3>()' is ambiguous
    return first + sum<Rest...>();
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue here is that `sum<Rest...>()` when `Rest` is empty won't call `int sum()` because that function is not a template.

When you change it to

```
template<int first>
int sum { return first; }
```

then the issue becomes that `template<int first> int sum` and `template <int first, int ...Rest> int sum()` with `Rest` being empty resolve to being the same function.  There are no rules about a tie break here so you get a compiler error.

The old way to fix this was to just add another template parameter to the variadic template giving you an overload set of

```
template <int first>
int sum() {
   return 0;
}

template <int first, int second, int ...Rest>
int sum() {
   return first + sum<second, Rest...>();
}
```

and with that once `Rest` is empty the only viable function to call is `template <int first> int sum()`

Now that we have fold expressions this isn't needed anymore and you can just use

```
template <int... Vals>
int sum() {
   static_assert(sizeof...(Vals) > 0, "You must provide at least one template parameter");
   return (... + Vals);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, you might do:

```
template <int first, int ...Rest>
int sum() {
   return (first + ... + Rest);
}
```

Alternative would be to use class and specialization:

```
template <int N, int Is...>
struct sum
{
    int operator () () const { return N + sum<Is...>{}(); }
};

template <int N>
struct sum<N>
{
    int operator () () const { return N; }
};
```

Comment: You don't need `first` as in `template <int ...Rest>
int sum() {
   return (... + Rest);
}`

Comment: @Ayxan: Not the same though, you "allow" `sum<>()` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Xy3-dp) (but fails to handle it correctly). OP only accepts 1+ arguments.

Comment: We can make it fail and even add a meaningful message [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pSX_wt)

Comment: @Ayxan: I would prefer the C++20 way then [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EjevWk)

Comment: Yes! That looks better with explicit constraints. I haven't looked into `requires` much; Is there a way to added a message as in `static_assert(bool, message)` version? I guess we could add a comment.